# Query to combine 2 column into 1 from same table

Tags: sql-server

How can I write a query from table `MDCCategories`to combine column `MDC` and `MDCText` into 1 column seperated by a hyphen "`-`"? Here is the table struct:

[image]

Please, let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT MDC + '-' + MDCText As MDC_New
FROM MDCCategories
```